# Adjective for something that is spread out or not concentrated in a single location

Tags: adjectives

I am looking for an adjective to describe something that cannot be found in a single location. For example, teaching jobs are spread out throughout the country, in cities and counties. They are not all concentrated in a single city and town.

Is there an adjective that I can use to describe teaching jobs? An adjective that means "spread out" or "not concentrated in a single location".

Comment: "Widespread", "disseminated", "dispersed" are a few options.  You should be able to Google synonyms for any of these words and for "spread out", too, with some good results.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for a single word meaning 'not concentrated in a single location' that can be used in one or both of these slots? (a) There are ___   jobs available in teaching. (b) Jobs in teaching are ___, unlike jobs in the lead-mining industry.

Answer (score 4):

**Teaching jobs are [geographically] distributed.**

> 2. (**be distributed**) Occur throughout an area: 
>    Examples: 
>     *the birds are mainly
>      distributed in marshes and river valleys 
>
>      A further 30 species were primarily confined to freshwater riparian areas distributed throughout the park.
>
>      The fat was distributed delicately yet densely throughout the meat, looking almost like snow.
>
>      A climbing fern Lygodium japonicum is classified into the Filicales and is distributed throughout the warm temperate areas in
>      Japan.* 
>    -- http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/distribute

Comment: I don't know why this had a downvote. Distributed seems to fit quite well

Comment: Didn't know it _had_ a downvote.  Some people are very funny.  'Distributed' seems to be an _excellent_ suggestion (i.e. it was my first thought, too), and I don't see the offence in providing a reference.

Comment: ... I'd say it was because the bare participial adjective doesn't work: *the birds are [mainly] distributed / *A climbing fern Lygodium japonicum is classified into the Filicales and is distributed ... are unacceptable. In my opinion, this doesn't deserve a downvote (or an upvote) though.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I disagree.  'Distributed' can mean simply 'not concentrated', and neither word _needs_ qualification in that sense.  To take your cue...  'Surveys consistently show that the birds are typically concentrated [in one or more unspecified locations], even though the worms are always distributed [by statistical comparison].'  The usage would be specialised (which is what OP is after) but in no way perverse.

Comment: @Captain Cranium The first 50 Google hits for "the birds are distributed" contains no unembellished (ie discounting 'where / how the birds are distributed' / 'the birds are distributed sparsely' / 'the birds are distributed over ... ' ...) adjectival usages. Perhaps you could find an example. If so, you might go on to see how common the usage is. // I don't see how 'teaching jobs' (which is an example of what OP 'is after') fits with a specialist register.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Don't be silly, and stop being disingenuous. OP is specifically after 'something that cannot be found in a single location', but is nevertheless identifiable in many instances. Two Answers here have suggested this solution, so respond sensibly to those. If this site were a Google-vote, neither you nor I should be bothering to contribute to it. Contribute to answers, and stop inventing Googlestats. This site is about applying helpful expertise to specific problems, not competing. Networks are distributed. Mail is regularly distributed. Goodwill is distributed.

Comment: @Captain Cranium I can find no examples, in a general search on the internet or on Google Ngrams, of "teaching jobs are distributed". The only example of a bare adjectival example of 'distributed' I can find is in the computing domain. I'm responding sensibly to the answers here: 'Teaching jobs are distributed rather than concentrated in a single location' is at best unidiomatic. I await your providing any evidence to the contrary. // Are you claiming that 'distributed' in 'mail is distributed' is an adjective?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Try to remember that we are trying to serve the Question here, regardless of your horrible examples.

For current purposes I quite like, 'The extent to which knowledge is distributed or concentrated can influence which approach is used to gather that knowledge' (Lawrence and Klimberg, Advances in Business and Management Forecasting, Volumes 3-9, Emerald Group, 2009, p163)

Or how about [_Permanent magnet synchronous motor with exterior‐rotor: Distributed or concentrated windings – motor performance comparison_](http://www.emeraldinsight.com/doi/abs/10.1108/03321640610666899)?

Comment: Captain Cranium But that is a 'cushioned' usage. 'The extent to which knowledge is distributed ...'. You wouldn't use 'Violence / Knowledge / Teaching posts is/are distributed.' in the same way you would 'Violence is widespread.', 'Bus stops are uniformly distributed.'  or 'Teaching posts are few and far between'. By the way, I didn't downvote here. I'm pointing out that questions need to be better defined. // I await your answer about the POS of 'distributed' in say 'goodwill is distributed'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I forgot to give the response to your specific question.  You seem to have spotted the _ambiguity_ in the 'mail' example.  Is it adjectival or not?  It really _could_ be, couldn't it? You suggested a need for examples, (presumably) to progress OP's enquiry, and I have spent time providing several including adapting one of your own. I am uninterested in your Googling challenges. Can we move on now, please?

Comment: Captain Cranium No: I totally reject your 'Don't be silly, and stop being disingenuous' comment. I'd expect an answer for OP's request for 'An adjective that means "spread out" or "not concentrated in a single location" to have a very similar distribution. I suggest you retract the 'silly' and 'disingenuous' misrepresentation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You are mistaken.  Look it up:  the knowledge quotation comes from a section headed 'Distributed Knowledge vs Concentrated Knowledge'.  This is unequivocally adjectival. And no-one is comparing this with 'widespread', so stop introducing random non-arguments.  The OP wanted something to contrast with _concentrated_, and this one works.  It isn't even my Answer, so stop arguing with me. In a rather different sense, _dispersed_ (which has also been suggested) would also work. It's OP's call, so you should stop obscuring things unnecessarily.

Comment: @Captain Cranium "Is there an adjective that I can use to describe teaching jobs?"  "Yes, say they're 'distributed'. "  // The reference you give even uses scare-quotes: "In general, knowledge about forecasting events of interest can be what we call “distributed” among ..." _Who_ is obscuring things?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, Edwin, jobs of some kind might very well be 'distributed' _as opposed to 'concentrated'_, depending on the viewpoint (for example OP's) that we are taking. They might also be described as 'cosy', 'calm' or 'contemplative'. They might very well be 'green', perhaps 'colourless', or maybe even 'furious'. In the statistical terms at stake here, some kind of job might be described as 'plentiful', 'sparse' or even 'flocking' by nature. It might even be 'imaginary'. Keep perspective, mind your ego, and don't disinform people seeking sensible, reasoned cases.

Comment: @Captain Cranium A plentiful job? A sparse job? I think you need to listen to your own advice. ELU is intended to promote English as it is used by most people.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Since it was your idea to do all this logic-chopping, please try (for OP's benefit) to keep up with the grammar being used in each example.  Your challenges do not hold water: look closely at them again, and avoid misrepresenting the examples. Meanwhile, 'ELU is intended to promote English as it is used by most people' is a completely inappropriate and reactionary political manifesto unsupported by anything at all in meta. You demanded examples, you got them. Make a case or don't, but try to be nice rather than simply combative.

Comment: ELU is primarily for the benefit of a larger audience interested in learning how English actually works, not individuals with questions that may be interpreted on different levels.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see your problem now. You are confusing this with ELL, and also patronising that as a space where former practitioners of anything at all might pontificate about how they seem to remember languages working.

ELU is, actually, for individuals with specific questions about usage. They seek informed responses, from which to select material that serves their purposes. My job and yours, here, is to serve individuals on a voluntary basis.

This is NOT a platform to give you access to the 'larger audience' that you imagine. If that is your objective, just go and play with WordPress.

Comment: @ Captain Cranium I see your problem now.

Answer (score 4):

For the specific context you mention,
I believe that [***distributed***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/distributed) is the best choice;
to be more precise (and slightly pedantic),
use [***uniformly distributed***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution). 
One might also say [***scattered***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scattered), as in “scattered showers”. 
For the more general question of something that is spread out,
[***diffuse***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/diffuse) (spread out over a wide area) seems to fit.

In the context of chemistry,
the opposite of *concentrated* is [***dilute***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dilute).

Answer (score 1):

I'm no pedantic, but I like *ubiquitous*. This is just my personal opinion, but *distributed* sounds to me like it should be used with more tangible nouns like *distributing flyers or drugs*. Whereas *ubiquitous* sounds like it can be used with both tangible and nontangible things, like a teaching job.